# Error while moving messages in Outlook using Powershell

Tags: email, powershell, outlook, move

I am trying to use Powershell to automate a task in Outlook.  I want to output specific messages to a textfile, then move those selected messages to a new directory.  Below is my concept code for this:

```
Add-type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.outlook" | out-null
$olfolders = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.olDefaultFolders" -as [type]
$outlook = New-Object -ComObject outlook.application
$namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$inbox = $namespace.getDefaultFolder($olFolders::olFolderInBox)

$ProcessedFolder = $inbox.folders.Item('Cyber').items

$DateVar = get-date -Format yyyyMMdd
$OutputFile2 = "C:\temp\Cyberemaildump" + $DateVar + ".txt"
$messages = $inbox.Items | ? {$_.SenderName -match "Cyber"} > $OutputFile2
foreach($message in $messages){$message.move($ProcessedFolder)}

$ProcessedFolder | Group-Object -Property SenderName -NoElement |Sort-Object count
```

If I comment out the last two lines, the code works great.  If I leave them in, I get the following error:

```
The remote procedure call failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BE)
Outlookautomation.ps1:21 char:1
+ $messages = $inbox.Items | ? {$_.SenderName -match "Cyber"} > $OutputFile2
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
```

Comment: At a glance it looks like you set `$ProcessedFolder` to be an array of items within `Cyber`. You then try to move the messages to the *items* rather than the *folder*, so you need to find a way to reference the folder itself

Comment: Did you really mean the last 2 lines are commented out? The 3rd last line is the one with the error. On the error line you are assigning output to a variable and redirecting to file. I don't think that would work. I would expect `$messages ` to be empty/null and that @arco444 said

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869662.aspx)/[FindNext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff862482.aspx) or [Restrict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869597.aspx) methods of the Items class to get the subset of items that correspond to the condition.

Also be aware, Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment. See [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The error is RPC_S_CALL_FAILED which usually happens when Outlook closes when your code is running.

Also keep in mind that foreach cannot be used if you change the number of items in the collection by moving them. Use a down "for" loop from Items.Count down to 1.